# AngularJS ng-repeat not working with select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have assigned an array to an object named

```
processMapAttrib.auditNotifyUsers.unAssignedUsers
```

when I print the variable in HTML file using

```
<label>{{processMapAttrib.auditNotifyUsers.unAssignedUsers}}</label>
```

I get

```
[{"id":230,"name":"Parthiban V"},{"id":231,"name":"Kanna A"},{"id":252,"name":"jagadesh S"},{"id":253,"name":"saravana kumar"},{"id":346,"name":"sith user"},{"id":347,"name":"seventh user"},{"id":348,"name":"unlimited user"}]
```

processMapAttrib has other values too. say like processMapAttrib.Process= {}, processMapAttrib.task = {},......

but when I use this in ng-repeat then its not working.

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="{{list.id}}" ng-repeat="list in processMapAttrib.auditNotifyUsers.unAssignedUsers">{{list.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Please help me in populating the data into select options.

Comment: show some more and related code

Comment: _when I print the variable_........ You mean this `console.log(processMapAttrib.auditNotifyUsers.unAssignedUsers)`?

Comment: use don't you use `processMapAttrib.auditNotifyUsers.unAssignedUser‌​s` t o ng-repeat

Comment: @sachilaranawaka OP is already doing that???

Comment: @Vegeta then just use this `list in processMapAttrib`?

Comment: Are you define your 'processMapAttrib' variable attached to $scope ? for example $scope.processMapAttrib = {};

Comment: @Nuwan.Niroshana yes  I have it in $scope.

Comment: Is there a reason you are you using [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) instead of [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)?

Comment: See [AngularJS API Reference -
 Using `ng-repeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options) and [AngularJS API Reference - Choosing between `ngRepeat` and `ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#choosing-between-ngrepeat-and-ngoptions-)

Comment: `<label>{{processMapAttrib}}</label>`, what this contain?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [NgOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of NgRepeat, easy to use and a great directive to dynamically generate a list of option elements in the select element

Add this to your view

```
<select ng-options="user as user.name for user in processMapAttrib.auditNotifyUsers.unAssignedUsers" 
    ng-model="selectedOption"></select>
```

See plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/6wTd8ZmbcsV4OjT2WC2C?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem in my code. I have changed value attribute to ng-value. And its working fine.

```
 <option ng-value="list.id" ng-repeat="list in processMapAttrib.auditNotifyUsers.unAssignedUsers">{{list.name}}</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.processMapAttrib = [{
        "id": 230,
        "name": "Parthiban V"
    }, {
        "id": 231,
        "name": "Kanna A"
    }, {
        "id": 252,
        "name": "jagadesh S"
    }, {
        "id": 253,
        "name": "saravana kumar"
    }, {
        "id": 346,
        "name": "sith user"
    }, {
        "id": 347,
        "name": "seventh user"
    }, {
        "id": 348,
        "name": "unlimited user"
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label>{{processMapAttrib}}</label>
    <select multiple="multiple">
        <option value="{{list.id}}" ng-repeat="list in processMapAttrib">{{list.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Gets `"Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined"`

Comment: I cannot user processMapAttrib as such. I may contain other objects. Please see the edited question